# Difference in columns. Returning variable top duplicate results

Tags: mysql, duplicates, max

I have a query that returns the biggest difference in two columns. Lets say it's something like:

```
| result |
    5
    5
    5
    4
    4
    3
    2
```

How can I make it return all of the top results every time? (5, 5, 5)

I'm not looking for LIMIT 3, since the results vary and sometimes there's only one top number, etc.

The query I have now looks like this:

```
SELECT MAX(column1 - column2) as result
FROM table
WHERE othercolumn = somecondition
GROUP by id
ORDER BY results asc
```

Comment: Is this a possible use for a `HAVING` clause? (I'm not familiar with it, I'd have to look it up.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(column1 - column2) as result
FROM table
WHERE othercolumn = somecondition
GROUP by id
HAVING result = 
  (select max(column1 - column2) FROM table WHERE othercolumn = somecondition)
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: I still get all the values. Not the top duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but it might work

```
select *,column1-column2 as result from table where column1 - column2 = 
(SELECT (column1 - column2) as G
FROM table
ORDER BY G DESC limit 1)
```